# r merge data with different year

Tags: r

I would like to merge two data using different years.

My data are like the below with more than 1,000 firms with 20 years span.

And I want to merge data to examine firm A's ratio at t's impact on firm A's count at t+1.

```
Data A

firm   year   ratio
 A     1990    0.2
 A     1991    0.3
...
 B     1990    0.1
```

```
Data B
firm   tyear  count
 A     1990     2
 A     1991     6
...
 B     1990     4
```

```
Expected Output

firm year ratio count
 A   1990  0.2   6
```

Any suggestion for code to merge data?
Thank you

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried so far. Also, please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use `lag()` with `merge()`. This link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Does any of the two answers provided, solve the question for you? If yes, then please consider accepting one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started on the dataset, just make sure you do the right lag/lead transformation on the table.

```
library(data.table)
dt.a.years <- data.table(Year =seq(from = 1990, to = 2010, by = 1L))
dt.b.years <- data.table(Year =seq(from = 1990, to = 2010, by = 1L))

dt.merged <- merge(  x = dt.a.years
      , y = dt.b.years[, .(Year, lag.Year = shift(Year, n = 1, fill = NA))]
      , by.x = "Year"
      , by.y = "lag.Year")

>dt.merged
    Year Year.y
 1: 1990   1991
 2: 1991   1992
 3: 1992   1993
 4: 1993   1994
 5: 1994   1995
 6: 1995   1996
 7: 1996   1997
 8: 1997   1998
 9: 1998   1999
```

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
A$tyear = A$year+1
AB = merge(A,B,by=c('firm','tyear'),all=F)
```